# Notepad doesn't open files created by Gedit?

Tags: windows-8

I'm using c/c++ compiler on Ubuntu 14.04 and I've typed all the programs using Gedit text editor.

But the problem is that now I need to open them in Windows 8 with Notepad, but when I tried to open `.c` files that are created in Ubuntu in Notepad they are displaying like a paragraph but not line by line.

So I need the programs to be displayed line by line as in Gedit . The only method I found was to edit each and every line in the program as to be displayed as line by line.

Comment: Just don't use notepad... it just doesn't support UTF-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true that Notepad is not a good editor and that it's basically Notepad's fault. But the actual problem is this:
Line ends are stored differently among operating systems. Unix (Ubuntu) usually use the symbol "LF" and Windows (Notepad too, because of that) "CR+LF".
You can set the line ends to CR+LF in Gedit (you need to search the option yourself, you should find it somewhere) and Notepad will be happy.
But in the long term you'll be happier with Notepad++ or I think Geany runs on Windows too.

Comment: where `LF` stands for "Line Feed", and `CR` stands for "Carriage Return" — as in, old typewriters. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types).

Answer (score 0):

Notepad is not a good editor.
Try to use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) the code should be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @giuseppe and @Nobidy, notepad++ is the best choice. However you can use also wordpad, which is provided with the operating system.